# Where do I input values?

Tags: java

Java Gurus,

Working on a class assignment and we are given a set of two programs. One calls on another to calculate interest rate, balances, etc for a bank account. What I am having problems with, is figuring out where I am supposed to input the variables we are given to get a successful compile for our program. Below are the two Java files we were given. I made the adjustments to correct all the purposeful errors in the code so everything compiles nicely so far.

```
public class BankAccount {
    private double balance; // Account balance
    private double interestRate; // Interest rate
    private double interest; // Interest earned

    /**
     * The constructor initializes the balance
     * and interestRate fields with the values
     * passed to startBalance and intRate. The
     * interest field is assigned to 0.0.
     */
    public BankAccount(double startBalance, double intRate) {
        balance = startBalance;
        interestRate = intRate;
        interest = 0.0;
    }

    /**
     * The deposit method adds the parameter
     * amount to the balance field.
     */
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    /**
     * The withdraw method subtracts the
     * parameter amount from the balance
     * field.
     */
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    /**
     * The addInterest method adds the interest
     * for the month to the balance field.
     */
    public void addInterest() {
        interest = balance * interestRate;
        balance += interest;
    }

    /**
     * The getBalance method returns the
     * value in the balance field.
     */
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * The getInterest method returns the
     * value in the interest field.
     */
    public double getInterest() {
        return interest;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Program2.java` which is what we need to compile:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat; // Needed for 2 decimal place amounts
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account; // To reference a BankAccount object
        double balance, // The account's starting balance
            interestRate, // The annual interest rate
            pay, // The user's pay
            cashNeeded; // The amount of cash to withdraw

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Create an object for dollars and cents
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        // Get the starting balance.
        System.out.print("What is your account's " + "starting balance? ");
        balance = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Get the monthly interest rate.
        System.out.print("What is your monthly interest rate? ");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Create a BankAccount object.
        account = new BankAccount(balance, interestRate);

        // Get the amount of pay for the month.
        System.out.print("How much were you paid this month? ");
        pay = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Deposit the user's pay into the account.
        System.out.println("We will deposit your pay " + "into your account.");
        account.deposit(pay);
        System.out.println("Your current balance is %bodyquot; + formatter.format( account.getBalance()  )");

        // Withdraw some cash from the account.
        System.out.print("How much would you like " + "to withdraw? ");
        cashNeeded = keyboard.nextDouble();
        account.withdraw(cashNeeded);

        // Add the monthly interest to the account.
        account.addInterest();

        // Display the interest earned and the balance.
        System.out.println("This month you have earned %bodyquot; + formatter.format( account.getInterest() )" +
            " in interest.");
        System.out.println("Now your balance is %bodyquot; + formatter.format( account.getBalance() ) )");
    }
}
```

What I am required to enter is 500 for Starting Balance, 0.00125 for Monthly Interest Rate (Interest is compounded monthly in the code and pretty sure I know where to put this variable), 1000 Monthly Pay and 900 withdrawl amount. The end result should be $600.75.

Is all of my code there or do I need to declare the value of the variables Starting Balance, Interest Rate, Monthly Pay and Withdrawl Amount?

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong, or if the answer is smack in front of my face and I am just blind today.

Comment: If some of your code is not compiling then please post what errors you are receiving.

Comment: I didn't read your full question, still if you are trying to input from command line. [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) might help. It's shorter than your question.

Comment: It is compiling. No errors received. What I am trying to figure out is where do I input the 500, 1000 and 900 for starting balance, monthly pay and withdrawal amount?

Comment: SO is not a home work machine.

Comment: You can enter that stuff into your console (since you're reading from `System.in`).

Comment: When you run this program it should print `What is your account's starting balance?`. Just type in the console right next to this.

Comment: Not asking you to do my homework bhspencer. Just looking for a little direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a copy paste issue in your code.

Change **From:**

```
System.out.println("Your current balance is %bodyquot; + formatter.format( account.getBalance()  )");
```

**To:**

```
 System.out.println("Your current balance is " + formatter.format( account.getBalance()  ));
```

Use below mentioned updated code.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat; // Needed for 2 decimal place amounts
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account; // To reference a BankAccount object
        double balance, // The account's starting balance
            interestRate, // The annual interest rate
            pay, // The user's pay
            cashNeeded; // The amount of cash to withdraw

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Create an object for dollars and cents
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        // Get the starting balance.
        System.out.print("What is your account's " + "starting balance? ");
        balance = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Get the monthly interest rate.
        System.out.print("What is your monthly interest rate? ");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Create a BankAccount object.
        account = new BankAccount(balance, interestRate);

        // Get the amount of pay for the month.
        System.out.print("How much were you paid this month? ");
        pay = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Deposit the user's pay into the account.
        System.out.println("We will deposit your pay into your account.");
        account.deposit(pay);
        System.out.println("Your current balance is " + formatter.format( account.getBalance()  ));

        // Withdraw some cash from the account.
        System.out.print("How much would you like to withdraw? ");
        cashNeeded = keyboard.nextDouble();
        account.withdraw(cashNeeded);

        // Add the monthly interest to the account.
        account.addInterest();

        // Display the interest earned and the balance.
        System.out.println("This month you have earned " + formatter.format( account.getInterest() ) +
            " in interest.");
        System.out.println("Now your balance is " + formatter.format( account.getBalance() ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to input those values either when you create your BankAccount class in your second program or at runtime. You could try something like this:

```
BankAccount account = new BankAccount(500, 0.00125)
```

And then input the rest of the values at runtime, or you could create local variables in Program 2 for everything and then create a new BankAccount using them as parameters.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you all. That is exactly the direction I am going with. I will work on it and see if I can figure the rest out. Greatly appreciated as always!

Comment: Good luck! Here's a link for oracle's constructor's documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html.

Comment: Thank you all again for the help. Now that the assignment is over I cannot believe how simple it actually was. I have noticed since I started learning Java I over analyze what is being asked of me to do and end up complicating something that should be really simple. Thank you again.